# What am i missing here or i should be doing differently?

Tags: java, java-11

I have just started learning about classes in Java so I am not sure what I am missing here or what I should be doing differently.
This is what I am doing:

```
class Student {

    private int roll;
    private String name;
    public void hW(){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}

public class classes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("hello");  
      Student s = new Student();
      s.hW();
      // TODO code application logic here

    }
}
```

It's giving this error when I run this file:

```
error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Student
```

What changes should I make??

**I am using Netbeans IDE 11.3 on macOSX**

Comment: You should only put a single class into a single file

Comment: Works for me, make sure that you have saved your file/files and recompile.

Comment: I ran your code with no issue.  I had both classes in the same file, named "classes.java".  But as mentioned by Lino this isn't best practice.

Comment: @Lino, `Students` is not public, so it is OK.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is OK yes, but not good practice, that's why I used "*should*"

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Your whole answer is based on assumptions of what the OP does when executing the code, meaning that these assumptions may hold or simply shatter, making the answer useless in the latter case. I propose to close the question with the reason that it needs more details / should be clarified

Comment: @Lino - OP is a beginner and he/she doesn't seem to know different options to execute the file. So, the only way to help him was to try all the ways and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you haven't mentioned in your question how you were trying to run the file, I was able to reproduce the issue with some hit and trial. Here is what you trying to do and why you faced the issue:

1. You have created `classes.java` in your IDE and in this file, you have typed the code which you have posted.
2. Now, you are going to Mac OS Terminal window and trying to run `java classes.java` probably thinking of **Java 11 feature which allows you to run a single-file program without compiling**.

## Why you faced the problem?

You faced the problem because `class Student` is at the top but it does not have `public static void main(String[] args)` while this feature of Java requires the top-level class to be executable (i.e. having this `main` method)

Check the following paragraph from https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

> In source-file mode, execution proceeds as follows:
>
> The class to be executed is the first top-level class found in the
>   source file. It must contain a declaration of the standard public
>   static void main(String[]) method.

## What is the solution?

Any of the following will work:

1. Move the class, `classes` up so that it becomes the first class in your file. Since the class, `classes` already has `public static void main(String[] args)`, your command, `java classes.java` will execute it without any problem.
2. Put the following piece of code inside `class Student` and execute `java classes.java` from the Terminal window.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("hello");  
    Student1 s = new Student1();
    s.hW();
}
```

3. Execute the following command from the Mac OS Terminal window to run your class in the pre-Java11 way:

```
javac classes.java
java classes
```

4. Execute the file from your IDE.

On a side note, you should follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the class, `classes` should be `Classes` as per the naming conventions.

Comment: I have re-read the question and fail to see how you deduce point number 2.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - OP is a beginner and he/she seem to know different options to execute the file. So, the only way to help him was to try all the ways and reproduce the issue. You can reproduce the issue in the only way mentioned in point#2.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you so much for the Answer and explaining in such simple terms. i read all your points and point number 1 did the trick for me.I would like to point out though that i was running the file from the IDLE itself and not the terminal.Also will keep point 4 in my mind.

Comment: @Aryan - You are most welcome. Wish you success!

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you so much ! One last thing -
what does OP mean in this comment by you,"@ScaryWombat - OP is a beginner and he/she seem to know different options to execute the file. So, the only way to help him was to try all the ways and reproduce the issue. You can reproduce the issue in the only way mentioned in point#2. – Arvind Kumar Avinash "

Comment: OP is an abbreviation of `Original Poster` i.e. the one who has posted the question. Since it's easy to type, it's most commonly used on Stack Overflow instead of the term, `Original Poster`. Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange for more details. I also made a typing mistake when I posted the message to @ScaryWombat. I meant, `OP is a beginner and he/she doesn't seem to know different options ...`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Okay.
Can you also refer a site or youtube channel from where I can learn about classes,constructors etc

Comment: @Aryan - You can check the tutorial, https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/prog-140388.html. I will try to find some more good videos and post them here.

Comment: @Aryan - I am not sure if you know YouTube channel, [Java Brains](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYt1sfh5464XaDBH0oH_o7Q). It's one of the best to learn basics. Also, do check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DC5wtYGQ7XE

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Sure thing. Thanks!